# Function after forEach execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I am trying to console.log() after a forEach function using Async/Await or Callback(). But neither of them seems to be working. Here is the set of functions I am trying to execute.

```
addAirports = async(airportsJson, callBack) => {
    await airportsJson.forEach( async(airport) => {        
        let db_find = await airportsModel.find({iata_code: airport.iata_code});
        if (db_find[0] == null) {
            airportsModel.insertMany(airport, function(error, docs) {});
            console.log(airport)
        }
    });
    callBack()
};

airportsUpdated = () => {
    console.log("All airports are updated")
}

addAirports(airportsInput, airportsUpdated);
```

I have even tried using ".map". It would be great if someone can tell me how can I achieve a async execution using Async/Await or Callback but by NOT using timeout.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't await its callbacks. `await airportsJson.forEach` won't do what you think it does.

Comment: I have tried "map" too

Comment: Same thing. An alternative would e.g. be `for (airport of airportsJson) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: That works could you post it as an answer please because there is no other similar question that has straight answer as your :).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: you need to add await to the function call `await addAirports(airportsInput, airportsUpdated);` and you do not need `await` before forEach `await airportsJson.forEach`

Comment: Yes it does, thanks   @ASDFGerte

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't use **forEach** because it doesn't work as you expect, instead, you can use **for of** in this way:

```js
addAirports = async (airportsJson, callBack) => {
  for (const airports of airportsJson) {
    let db_find = await airportsModel.find({ iata_code: airport.iata_code });
    if (db_find[0] == null) {
      airportsModel.insertMany(airport, function (error, docs) {});
      console.log(airport);
    }
  }

  callBack();
};

airportsUpdated = () => {
  console.log("All airports are updated");
};

addAirports(airportsInput, airportsUpdated);
```